# Emtpy Data of Column in Item when Workflow successfully Rejects or Approves

Tags: workflow

I have created my own approval workflow.when Workflow successfully has done , i see Page content or Text Editor is Empty when Item copies to other library.i checked View Setting and Permission too.

See Picture here :

http://www.imagetoo.com/images/test2.jpg

Comment: Behrouz, can you show the workflow steps... upload an image of Update Item action!

Comment: here image :

http://i47.tinypic.com/2usxt1h.jpg

forget about Approving Process just Focus Rejecting Process.
Content Approval is enable in both Libraries (Pending Ideas & Rejected).

also i downloaded UsefulSPDWorkflowActivities_0.5.0.zip 
from http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behrouz,

The problem is with the Copy List Item action of SharePoint Designer, see following post:
[SharePoint Designer Copy List Item Workflow Activity Does Not Copy All Fields](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/johnwpowell/sharepoint-designer-copy-list-item-workflow-activity-does-not-copy-all-fields)

I would suggest to Create a New Item in Rejected Idea list and set each field you need to propagate!

I hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks.issue is now Fixed.according to John W Powell :

Compare the settings between the source field and target field.  Does one allow multiple values and the other does not?

also The source and target field should be the same type.